# How to fix syntax error in SQLite in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I've finished making some SQLite tables and am executing the instructions. When executing the instructions, the following error has come up:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Category": syntax error
```

Most of my tables use the same sort of format, below is an example of one such table.

```
CategoryTableSQL = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category(
                            CategoryID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                            Category text NOT NULL
                        );"""
databaseNewTable(Connection, CategoryTableSQL)
```

Comment: , after `AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a comma between the declaration of your table fields in your SQL-statement: It should be like this. Always use comma's to seperate the field-creation statements. Except of course, for the last field you create =). Also, I would take care in naming your fields the same name as your tables. To prevent confusion. Just my two cents

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category(
                            CategoryID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            Category text NOT NULL
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You just need to add the ',' symbol after the AUTOINCREMENT word. :-)
Like this:

```
CategoryTableSQL = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category(
                        CategoryID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        Category text NOT NULL
                    );"""
databaseNewTable(Connection, CategoryTableSQL)
```

Comment: Oops, I'm late. :-)